# Why is there a pdb file in my Release directory?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

When I build a **release** version of a project in Visual Studio 2008, it creates a .pdb file, e.g. for a simple WPF project it generates a .exe and .pdb file.

I've always understood [.pdb files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database) to be for **debugging**, so I would expect them to be in the **Debug** folder but not the **Release** folder.

And looking around at other StackOverflow questions, it doesn't seem that [pdb files work well with teh Release version anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769995/debugging-a-release-version-of-a-dll-with-pdb-file).

**Why are .pdb files generated in the Release folder by default and how can I turn that option off?**

Answer (score 5):

You are right. PDB files are for debugging but you may need to debug release builds too. Saving PDBs of released builds is very important when you want to debug a customer issue and you have the crash dump file related to that issue.

By the way, generating PDB files does not harm compiler optimizations. If you don't ship it to the customer, there will be no performance implications.

Comment: +1 for generating .pdb files doesn't harm compiler optimizations.  I think it's a common misconception that it does harm optimizations.  I can't think of any good reason to not generate pdb's for release builds unless you're for some reason concerned about disk space conservation, can you?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the project settings. Just happens that in Release version a .pdb is also generated by default. It will not hurt you - just don't ship it to the customer.

To skip its creation go to Linker->Debugging in project settings and set "Generate Debug Info" to "No".