# Why does Visual Studio 2010 compiler for VB.Net still generate pdb files in my bin folder when I have "Generate debug info" set to "None"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation, pdb-files

1. Delete all pdb files from Project/bin folder.
2. In project settings -> Compi9le -> Advanced, set 'Generate debug info' to 'None' (instead of pdb-only).
3. Recompile project (in Release mode, with Generate debug info == None).
4. Visual studio creates pdb files in my project's bin folder even though Generate debug info is still None.

Why?  And how can I get Visual Studio to stop generating these pdb files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there a pdb file in my Release directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642371/why-is-there-a-pdb-file-in-my-release-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain that you have changed it for the correct build config. eg. You changed it for Release but you are compiling under debug?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm certain that I'm compiling in Release, and have changed the option in Release mode.  I've just repeated the steps in my original post to confirm.

Comment: I have done a few tests and found that it works fine but if you have a multiple project solution and your project references another project which is creating the .pdb files they will be copied to your build folder. Are you sure they are .pdb files for your current project?