# When debugging I can step into my NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, nuget, nuget-package

I created a brand new NuGet package for internal use

it is:

- private, not published on the NuGet repo
- compiled in release mode

However, I'm able to step into the provided API! How can it be?

NOTE:
I moved away the actual source code. The project which is using the package doesn't "see" the package source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Release builds produce [PDB files](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know). Among other information, these PDB files contain locations of source files.

When you step through your code, Visual Studio loads the PDB file, from there it extracts full paths to source files, and as long as it can access them (which it can, provided that you've built your NuGet package locally), you get to step though library code.

Comment: are you sure that PDB files are generated on a release build?

Comment: Yep. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5457095/60188 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371032/60188 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642371/60188

Answer (score 1):

just dont publish the pdb file :)

PS: if your VS knows the path to the sources from your Nuget Package, he will still be able on your PC to do a Step by Step debug.