# publishing debug versions of asp.net dlls

Tags: asp.net, debugging, release-mode

I'm a little confused about using release vs. debug versions of a dll for a live site.  We have code written so that when the site experiences an uncaught exception it runs through the exception and any inner exception and emails us the details.  I've read that it's best for performance to only use release version dlls but I wondered if we went that route, would that still allow us to inspect the exceptions and get line numbers and so forth about where the error occurred?  Or do we have to have the debug version out there to get that information?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the debug version of the DLLs deployed to your servers.
If you deploy a release version of the dlls along with the pdb files, your exceptions should still contain line numbers.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563000/can-optimizations-affect-the-ability-to-debug-a-vc-app-using-its-pdb/567886)